# Symfony 6, form textarea not posted after submiting the form

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, symfony-forms, symfonyux

I have simple contact form:

```
<form id='contactform' action="{{ path('app_contact_send') }}" method="POST" name="contactform">
    <ul class="form-cover">
        <li class="inp-name">
            <label>Nombre * (requerido)</label>
            <input id="name" type="text" name="your-name">
        </li>
    <li class="inp-text">
            <label>Mensaje * (requerido)</label>
            <textarea id="mess" name="mess"></textarea>
        </li>
        <li class="inp-email">
            <label>E-mail * (requerido)</label>
            <input id="email" type="email" name="your-email">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="btn-form-cover">
        <button id="#submit" type="submit" class="btn">enviar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

After clicking the submit button I have a controller that gathers data from the from:

```
        $name = $request->request->get('name');
        $from = $request->request->get('email');
        $mess = $request->request->get('mess');
```

Then use the data to sent an email with symfony mailer in a POST method in the controller:

```
$email = (new Email())
        ->from($from)
        ->replyTo($from)
        ->to('some@email.com')
        ->cc('another@email.net')
        ->bcc('bcc@email.com')
        ->replyTo($from)
        ->subject('Mensaje desde www.website.com')
        ->text(sprintf('Mensaje enviado: %s, por: %s.', $mess, $name));
```

Email is sent but variable 'mess' gathered form textarea is always empty, name and email have values.

Is anything more I have to do for textarea type fielsds?

Requests are managed by Symfony UX Turbo.

variable mess should have a value.

Comment: No, nothing more to do. "_name and email have values_" In your mail? Or in your code? What debugging have you done? `var_dump($_POST)`? Did you check the DevConsole on what gets sent? How do you implement the fields when sending mail?

Comment: I'm confused - your HTML form is set up to send data using the named fields `your-name`, `mess` and `your-email`, yet you're receiving data using `name`, `email` and `mess`.  Are you using some JavaScript code to submit the form, or is it a standard HTML form submission?

Comment: @brombeer yes name and email have values on the sent email, mess is empty. var_dump($_POST) does not show anything I believe cause UX Turbo is managing the clicks an I only get the flash message update on the page.

Comment: @RobEyre ID parameter is used to get the post variable.

Comment: 'ID parameter is used to get the post variable' - so that's different to how standard HTML forms work, which means you must be using some client-side JavaScript to send the data to your PHP code.  This is missing from your question description.  Please could you share more information about how you're actually submitting the form.

Comment: @MiguelMejia Please mention in your question or the tags that you are using UXTurbo - this is changing form submissions to AJAX

Answer (score 1):

I did track this down to a js file where the mouse click is being captured, the form values posted to an array.

Modify this to match the fields on the form.

This solve the problem.